# C++ Looping and Increments

Tags: c++, loops, increment

Im trying to split my data up into 256 byte chunks, but as my loop runs, it seems to double in size. So it starts at 256 then 512, then 1024, 2048, 4096, etc; instead of being multiple chunks of 256.

```
        while (Start < dwFileSize)
        {
            Finish += Start + (256);

            if (Finish > dwFileSize) Finish = dwFileSize;

            WriteChunk(szFilename, ZipID, &lpFileBuffer[Start], Finish-Start);

            ZipID++;
            Start = Finish;
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: That's because of `Finish += Start + (256);`. It should be a `=`.

Comment: This line `Finish += Start + (256);` adds `256` each iteration to `Finish`.

Answer (score 1):

try...

```
    while (Start < dwFileSize)
    {
        Finish = min(Start + 256, dwFileSize);

        WriteChunk(szFilename, ZipID, &lpFileBuffer[Start], Finish-Start);

        ZipID++;
        Start += 256;
    }
```